# Самая короткая сортировка массива без использования Array.prototype.sort()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

На собеседовании задали вопрос: "Как отсортировать массив, не используя метод .sort(), посредством ES6, при этом код не должен занимать более двух строк".

Уже битый час ломаю над этим голову, ничего не могу придумать.

Comment: сортировать что? числа? строки? объекты неограниченной вложенности? космос?

Comment: Сортировка чисел

Comment: Как хак - можно написать любую свою реализацию и просто её расположить в одну строку ;)

Comment: Я тоже так отшутился, но это не то, что от меня хотели.

Comment: ES2015 не добавляет каких-то специальных функций для сортировки, то есть в любом случае, чтобы _отсортировать_ массив, нужно применить к нему sort, не важно из прототипа или любой внешний

Comment: _но это не то, что от меня хотели_ - почему ты так думаешь? :-) вообще условие _две строки_ для языка в котором _любой код_ можно записать в одну строку - странно

Comment: Алгоритм можно использовать любой, хоть пузырьки, главное, чтобы код был очень компактный (2 строки)

Comment: Если чисто на листочке бумаги с ручкой сразу на собеседовании - то это сложно в голове придумать. Мне кажется даже чуваку уровня выше миддла. При наличие интернета и гугла функций js - можно вроде что-то нарисовать.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, только непонятно чем это будет отличаться от написания обычной функции сортировки пузырьком

Comment: @Grundy хз) типа нестандартное мышление))

Answer (score 2):

Получилось как-то так:

```js
let arr = [5,6,4,3,7];
console.log('input: ' + arr);

let obj = arr.reduce((o, v, i) => { o[v] = v; return o; }, {});
arr = Object.keys(obj).map(num => parseInt(num));

console.log('output: ' + arr);
```

В одну строку сократить)))

```js
let arr = [5,6,4,3,7];
console.log('input: ' + arr);

arr = Object.keys(arr.reduce((o, v, i) => { o[v] = v; return o; }, {})).map(num => parseInt(num));

console.log('output: ' + arr);
```

Может и есть косяки. О чем наверняка другие с радостью подскажут

**UPD:** т.к. вышеописанный способ возвращает отсортированный массив и при этом неповторяющиеся элементы (то есть при входе `5,4,4,7,3` получи `3,4,5,7`), то вот еще версия....по просьбам телезрителей, чтоб в результирующем массиве были и дубликаты, если имеются

```js
let arr = [5, 3, 6, 4, 4, 7];
console.log('input: ' + arr);
let arrCopy = arr.slice(0, arr.length);
let result = [];

arrCopy.forEach((el, i) => {
  let index = min = 0;
 
  arr.reduce((a, b) => { min = (a <= b) ? a : b; return min; })
    
  index =  arr.indexOf(min);

  result.push(i == arrCopy.length - 1 ? arr[0] : arr[index]);

  arr.splice(index, 1);   
});

console.log('output: ' + result);
```

и последний на сегодня:

```js
let arr = [5, 3, 6, 4, 4, 7];
 console.log('input: ' + arr);
 let arrCopy = arr.slice(0, arr.length);
 let result = [];

 arrCopy.forEach(() => {
   let minElementIndex = 0;

   minElementIndex = arr.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, arr));

   result.push(arr[minElementIndex]);
   arr.splice(minElementIndex, 1);
 });

 console.log('output: ' + result);
```

Comment: отсортируйка мне такой массив: `[5,4,4,6]` :P

Comment: @Grundy да в таком случае будет косяк... но тогда двух строчек точно не получится ибо нужно много операций.....дополнил еще одним кодом, но уже побольше строк там

Comment: ну зачем _map_ если ты из него ничего не возвращаешь :-)

Comment: @Grundy это была глубокая ночь. поправил на forEach

Answer (score 2):

На основе соседнего ответа с [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), бежим по исходному массиву и ищем куда вставить проверяемый элемент в конечный массив. поиск производится с помощью функции [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

*!!! Работает, даже в случае присутствия в массиве элементов с одинаковыми значениями !!!*

```js
let arr = [5, 6, 4, 3, 7];
console.log('input: ' + arr);

let sorted = arr.reduce((o, v) => {
  var index = o.findIndex(el => el > v);
  return ((index > -1) ? o.splice(index, 0, v) : o.push(v)), o;
}, []);


console.log('output: ' + sorted);

let arrDup = [5, 6, 4, 5, 7, 3, 3, 7];
console.log('input: ' + arrDup);

let sortedDup = arrDup.reduce((o, v) => {
  var index = o.findIndex(el => el > v);
  return ((index > -1) ? o.splice(index, 0, v) : o.push(v)), o;
}, []);


console.log('output: ' + sortedDup);
```

В большинстве решений все сводится к тому, что бы отобразить исходный массив в результирующий, выбирая каждый раз минимальный или максимальный элемент

```js
let arr = [5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 7];
console.log('input: ' + arr);

let sorted = arr.map(function(el) {
  return this.splice(this.indexOf(Math.min(...this)), 1)[0];
}, arr.slice());


console.log('output: ' + sorted);
```

Comment: и зачем так орать?))))

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = [3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4],
c = [];
for (; a.length;)  { c.push(a.splice(a.indexOf(Math.min(...a)),1)[0])}
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Родилось такое извращение:

```js
let arr = [3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4];
let sorted = [];
while (arr.length) 
    sorted = sorted.concat(arr.splice(arr.indexOf(arr.reduce((prev, cur) => prev < cur ? prev : cur)), 1));
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: `arr.reduce` в данном случае лучше заменить на `Math.min.apply(Math,arr)` хотя бы будет понятно что он делает :-)

Comment: А, логично. Голова вечером уже плохо варит, про существование Math банально забыл. Исправлять уже не буду. :)

Comment: @Grundy Yaant решение неплохое.... но на собеседовании такое родить по-моему крайне тяжело))